# warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'int'

Tags: c

Build log:

> warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'int'

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");///for a new line
    printf("Hello world ");///simple
    printf("enter some values = %d %d %f",54432,54,54.76474)
    printf("%d \n",232);///integer in new line
    printf("%f \n",21.322432);///decimal in new line
    printf("%ld \n",3809);///large integer in new line
    printf("%lf \n",432758575375735.24);///large float in new line

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integer literals (like `3809`) are by default `int`. On most modern systems `int` is a signed 32-bit type. The type of `long` *could* be signed 32 bits as well, but it's still a different type from `int`. Perhaps all you need is [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: Please refrain from posting profanity. Also, this error is fairly self-explanatory. Have you tried anything to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: BTW: `432758575375735.24` is not a `float`, but a _floating constant_ of type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The compiler warns you and then the `printf` tries to process `sizeof(long int)` bytes where you have provided it with an integer literal which is of size `sizeof(int)` bytes.

It expects `sizeof(long int)` bytes and now if `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)` It's alright else it's Undefined Behavior.

**Don't think that format specifier are similar to variables. `long` variable can hold values of an `int`. This doesn't go with the format specifiers.**

A casting would solve the problem

```
printf("%ld \n",(long)3809);
```

From standard `§7.21.6.1` (Formatted input/output functions)

> [7] If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Although I prefer to avoid casting, a cast of a constant in `printf(....)` is defensive programing.

Comment: @chux.: Yes kind of like that..I admit.

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants have type `int` by default.  The `"%ld"` format specifier expects a `long int`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

You need to add the `L` suffix for an integer literal to have type `long`:

```
printf("%ld \n",3809L);
```

Comment: "You need to add the L suffix for an integer literal to have type long" is almost on the money.  `1234567890123` would be a `long` on a 32-bit `int`/64-bit `long` even without an `L`.  Certainly an `L` is needed for constants in the `int` range.